# What happens if a botnet uses http requests to drain my Amazon AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spam, spam-prevention, ddos, fraud-prevention

Im going to launch an app and Im worried if my competitors would just kill me by draining my Amazon AWS resources by using a botnet to send gibberish http requests to my Amazon AWS Account. I only got a few thousand dollars and I can not afford to be slaughtered like that.

In what other ways my competitors or haters could drain my server resources to drain my bank balance and how to prevent it?

please help. Im in very stressful situation where I cant get any answer for this question. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @morras, `AWS Shield + WAF` is good combination to protect your resources from spam requests. Since you have not given your architecture about what aws services you are actually using, I am trying to answer based on general term.

In [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) there are two types

1. **Standard** - Automated mitigation techniques are built-into AWS Shield Standard, giving you protection against common, most frequently occurring infrastructure attacks. If you have technical expertise to create rules based on your request, you can go with this.
2. **Advanced** - AWS WAF comes free with this, and you will have 24x7 access to the AWS DDoS Response Team (DRT), support experts who apply manual mitigations for more complex and sophisticated DDoS attacks, directly create or update AWS WAF rules, and can recommend improvements to your AWS architectures.It also includes some cost protection against `Amazon EC2`, `Elastic Load Balancing`, `Amazon CloudFront`, and `Amazon Route 53` usage spikes that could result from scaling during a DDoS attack

Please take a look at [design resilient architecture in aws to mitigate DDOS](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-ddos-attack-mitigation/).

**update**: If the AWS Shield Advanced team determines that the incident is a valid DDoS attack and that the underlying services scaled to absorb the attack, AWS provides account credit for charges incurred due to the attack. For example, if your legitimate CloudFront data transfer usage during the attack period was 20 GB, but due to the attack you incurred charges for 200 GB of incremental data transfer, AWS provides credit to offset the incremental data transfer charges. AWS automatically applies all credits toward your future monthly bills. Credits are applied towards AWS Shield and cannot be used for payment for other AWS services. Credits are valid for 12 months.

*The services covered as per doc are Amazon CloudFront, Elastic Load Balancing, Route 53 or Amazon EC2 . Please check with AWS support, whether your services are covered or not.*

Comment: I understand AWS takes care of most of the problems like DDOS but is there any way to keep the service running even under DDOS attack without losing money?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options available. First of AWS provides [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) which is a DDoS protection service. The standard subscription is free and covers most frequently occurring network and transport layer DDoS attacks.

On top of that you can consider using [AWS WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) which allows you to setup rules for what traffic to allow to your servers.

You can also use [API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) in front of your service and set [throttling limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html) on how much traffic to allow through.

However I would question if you really need this? It sounds like you are worried that you would run up a huge AWS bill if competitors start sending you millions of requests. You can setup billing alerts so when your forecasted bill exceeds a specific threshold you are warned and you can either manually shut down the services that are being bombarded and figure out what the attacks look like, or you can have an automatic response via CloudWatch. I believe that you will find that you will not be under attack and that you should not worry too much on this attack vector at this time.

Comment: Im worried because Im going to start a Taxi Service app and the services cannot go offline or freeze ever. What to now?

Comment: " I believe that you will find that you will not be under attack and that you should not worry too much on this attack vector at this time." ---------------- I wonder exactly what makes you believe that I will not be under such attacks?

Comment: I am sorry if that sounded a bit harsh. I find the people tend to get worried about corner cases when they start out which gets them bogged down in details that are not helping them drive their business forward. Like how do I scale my application to a thousand requests per second or survive a full AWS region outtage? Very few companies are at a scale where spending time on these questions help them have a succesful product, instead it slows you down so you loose any advantage that you might have. 

--Focus on keeping user data safe and worry less about outages, and then learn if they happen.